# marginnote placed wrongly (linebreak) within an environment

Tags: environments, marginnote

Within an environment (see `environ`), I have a `marginnote` placed next to the environment header. The header contains some text. If that text extends towards the end of the line (but even a bit before that as the MWE shows), then the margin note is not placed next to the environment header anymore (it seems that a line break occurs in the `marginnote`). Why? And how can I fix the environment to avoid this? I guess there's an additional space (where?) generated from the environment header which then pushes the margin note to the next line.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Environment
\newcounter{counter}% environment counter
\numberwithin{counter}{chapter}% number counter within chapters
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{environ}[2][]{\refstepcounter{counter}\par
  \normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
\item[\hskip\labelsep\sffamily\bfseries MyEnviro~\thecounter\ #1]%
  \marginnote{OtherEnviro p.~\pageref{#2}}\ignorespaces
}{%
  \endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{That's the problem}

\begin{environ}[(Some text which covers the amount of space to show the problem)]{foobar}\\
  This seems odd (vertical space, wrong placement 'OtherEnviro') because the line
  is actually not ending there.
\end{environ}

\begin{environ}[(Some shorter text to show that there's no problem here)]{foobar}\\
  This is okay
\end{environ}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\marginnote` adds a invisible box, something like `\mbox{}`. The separation (`\labelsep`) after the `\item` in addition with the `\mbox{}` results in the empty line. BTW: Without this box your `\\` would result in a `LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.`

So to avoid the problem, set `\labelsep` to 0pt and (optionally) add the `\\` to the definition of the environment.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Environment
\newcounter{counter}% environment counter
\numberwithin{counter}{chapter}% number counter within chapters
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{environ}[2][]{\refstepcounter{counter}\par
  \normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \labelsep 0pt
\item[\hskip\labelsep\sffamily\bfseries MyEnviro~\thecounter\ #1]%
  \marginnote{OtherEnviro p.~\pageref{#2}}\\*
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{That's the problem}

\begin{environ}[(Some text which covers the amount of space to show the problem)]{foobar}
  This seems odd (vertical space, wrong placement 'OtherEnviro') because the line
  is actually not ending there.
\end{environ}

\begin{environ}[(Some shorter text to show that there's no problem here)]{foobar}
  This is okay
\end{environ}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've used `\\*` instead of `\\` to avoid page breaks immediately after the *heading*.